# Facebook invite problems, please help

Tags: facebook

We have created an invite function at our site in JavaScript using the Graph API where users can invite their Facebook friends to our site. The users invited then get an invite post at their wall on Facebook.

This has been workling fine until suddenly one day the messages did not show up on the invited users wall. We even still get post sucess messages from Facebook and a Post ID.

Also, we nocticed that old invite posts were removed as well from the Faceook walls. However, other functions with the same app ID still work.

When we created a new Facebook app with a new Facebook app ID the invite functions work like normal again.

As far as we know we arent breaching any rules or regulations, and we havent been notified by Facebook (although we are quite active with FB ads).

Is there some risk Facebook have blocked our app without telling us? Can they block our domain if we continue? Are there any general rules when it comes to invite? Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has many anti-spam policies and procedures in place. If a high enough percentage of users delete the post that gets added to their wall or mark it as spam or choose to hide all posts from your application, the application will get removed and the posts removed as you have experienced. They may or may not email you to warn you.

Facebook has a high level [guide to follow](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

**Create a great user experience**

- Build social and engaging applications
- Give users choice and control
- Help users share expressive and relevant content
- Be trustworthy

**Respect privacy**

- Don't mislead, confuse, defraud, or
  surprise users
- Don't spam - encourage authentic
  communications

I am guessing they are flagging your account for not helping users share expressive and relevant content (I am guessing they don't get to type the message that gets shared on friends wall), as well as obviously for spam.

If you want to invite users, I would suggest using the supported method for this, the Facebook [requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), and move away from posting (spamming) other friends walls, as they most likely can ban your whole website or account if you keep doing what you are doing.